# How do I remove select2 options based on the first selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a list of tests which appear in a select2 drop down. Whilst there is a longer list of tests, I need the number of options available to change depending on the first option which is selected. The tests are basically age group tests, so if a test for age 11 is chosen, I need to remove all other tests which are not 11. Likewise, if a test 10 is chosen, then it only keeps the other tests for age group 10 in the list.

I could put the values of the groups which needs showing in arrays to search through, but I'm not sure whether that helps. For example:

```
var age11tests = [1, 6, 10];
var age10tests = [2, 7, 11];
var age09tests = [3, 8, 12];
```

etc

```
<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" name="testnameIDlist" id="testnameIDlist">
<option value="1"> PTM 11</option>
<option value="2"> PTM 10 </option> 
<option value="3"> PTM 09 </option>
<option value="4"> PTM 08 </option>
<option value="5"> PTM 07 </option>
<option value="6"> PTE 11 </option> 
<option value="7"> PTE 10 </option>
<option value="8"> PTE 09 </option>
<option value="9"> PTE 08 </option> 
<option value="9"> PTE 08 </option>
<option value="10"> CAT 11 </option>
<option value="11"> CAT 10 </option> 
<option value="12"> CAT 09 </option>
<option value="13"> CAT 08 </option> 
<option value="14"> CAT 07 </option>
</select>
```

When no options are selected the whole list needs to be displayed. I'm not sure where to start!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi , if `PTM 11` is selected then all courses with `11` will be shown ?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Likewise with tests 10, and 09, and 08 etc.